# Spring Integration - Mockito.verify().someMethod () - error Wanted but not invoked

Tags: spring-integration

This is regarding the issue I am facing to test the service activator. Technologies used are - Spring Integration with Redis - using RedisQueueOutboundChannelAdapter and RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint.
The application code can be found at link https://github.com/SRekha-LV/SISamples/tree/master/SpringRedisTestEg
Flow - HomeController sends asynchronous messages to the Service Activator method  - processQueue1Details ()  in class ProcessQueue1Messages.

The intention is to test the no. of times the method - processQueue1Details  () is being called. The sample testcase for the same is in the test class - TestHitCount.java  - testProcessQueue1 ().

Executing this is giving an exception **"Wanted but not invoked:
processQueue1Messages.processQueue1Details(
    GenericMessage [payload=TEst, headers={timestamp=1457436349427, id=d1b622d4-43b1-dfc4-e114-2ae700cbdb6c}]
);
-> at com.spring.mvc.redis.TestHitCount.testProcessQueue1(TestHitCount.java:42)**
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock."

Need some help.

Thanks in advance for all the support.

Answer (score 0):

Your application is very complex and your question is enough dirty. That's why someone has de-voted your question already.

I really can't catch your your configs and test, but I have two advises:

1. In Spring Integration you should use `@ServiceActivator` for `MessageHandler` `@Bean`s. To be able to consume from the channel and handle message, e.g. send it to Redis List like all those your `RedisQueueOutboundChannelAdapter`s.
2. If you test the `async` scenario you have to **wait** for the result on the other hand before invoke the `.verify()`. E.g. in your case you send to the Redis and exit. There is really no any interaction with your `mock`.
3. Let's take a look to your code closer!

   ```
   @Test
   public void testProcessQueue1 () {
       ProcessQueue1Messages pQueue1Msgs =  Mockito.mock(ProcessQueue1Messages.class);
       Object strObj = "TEst";
       Message<Object> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(strObj).build();
       rulesRQOutboundChannelAdapter.handleMessage(message);

       Mockito.verify(pQueue1Msgs).processQueue1Details(message);
   }
   ```

You create `mock` in the test and nowhere provide it. So how your Spring Application should interact with the mock, if it is just local variable?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I admit it.

Comment: Actually this is  a sample code from my application. I am new to spring integration and writing tests using mockito. There is a requirement to test the message endpoints to ensure all the sent messages are handled correctly.  In this process I tried to create a test method to test only the message End point - ProcessQueue1Messages. The asynchronous calls in the controller are not being touched in this process. Hence didn't add any wait for the verify method.

Comment: OK. Please, take a look to your test-case code again. No one uses your `pQueue1Msgs` variable. It is dead code. How are going to verify it if you don't inject that `pQueue1Msgs` to some real service involved in your process. From other side `rulesRQOutboundChannelAdapter` just sends message to Redis, how are you going to verify if your message has reached Redis and has been popped from there properly, if you aren't going to wait for something?

Comment: The redis configurations are in the file - com.spring.mvc.config.AppRedisConfig.  The sample configuration for rulesRQoutboundChannelAdapter is

Comment: `@Bean  RedisQueueOutboundChannelAdapter rulesRQOutboundChannelAdapter () {                                                                                        RedisQueueOutboundChannelAdapter redisPublisher = new RedisQueueOutboundChannelAdapter(  rulesQueue, jedisConnectionFactory ());  return redisPublisher;                                         }`

Comment: `@Bean  RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint rulesRQMessageDrivenEndpoint() {   RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint redisEndPoint = new RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint(  rulesQueue, jedisConnectionFactory());  redisEndPoint.setOutputChannel(rulesQueueChannel());  redisEndPoint.setErrorChannel(errorChannel());  return redisEndPoint;  }`

Comment: The service activator declaration is:        `@MessageEndpoint  
public class ProcessQueue1Messages implements Queue1Messages{   
 @Override
 @ServiceActivator (inputChannel = "rulesQueueChannel",poller = @Poller(fixedDelay="10", taskExecutor="rulesExecutor"))
 public void processQueue1Details (Message<Object> strMsg) {
  String newMsg = strMsg.getPayload() + "\nHello Queue1";  
  try {
   actionRQOutbounChannelAdapter.handleMessage(MessageBuilder.withPayload(strMsg.getPayload()).build ());
  } catch (Exception e) { }
 }
}`

Comment: I need to write tests to ensure that the messages sent through the outbound channel adapter are being sent to the service activator method - **processQueue1Details** in ProcessQueue1Messages.   Any guideance in this context would be helpful.